# How to throw errors in a GraphQL subscription using HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphql, hotchocolate

I have an ASP .NET Core GraphQL API using HotChocolate.
It is possible to start a long-running operation using a mutation, in this case extracting a file.
I am using subscriptions to notify the user when the process is finished.
But if an exception occours, how to I throw it in the subscription?

My subscription:

```
[Subscribe]
public FilePayload FileExtracted([EventMessage] FilePayload file)
{
    return file;
}
```

How I am sending the event to the subscription from the service layer:

```
await _eventSender.SendAsync(nameof(FileSubscriptions.FileExtracted), zipFilePayload,
                    cancellationToken);
```

When I try to pass a second parameter of type Exception to the subscription, it just instantly terminates with an empty "errors" object.
What is the correct way of doing this?